# Can BNF consist of zero rules?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to use BNF to describe its own grammar to get used to it. What I can not find any information about is whether BNF must consist of ***zero or more rules*** or ***one or more rules***. The difference would be:

```
<grammar> ::= <grammar> <rule> | <rule>
```

vs.

```
<grammar> ::= <grammar> <rule> | ""
```

The only difference I can see is that an empty language can be described by an emtpy BNF in the second case, but must use `<grammar> ::= ""` in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concretely speaking, the Backus-Naur form is a notation for context-free grammars, applied to the (formal) description of languages at the syntactical level.

While there are extended versions of BNF that have been standardized, the BNF itself hasn't, so there is no way of determining if the empty grammar is "legal" BNF.

As a mathematical object, the possibility of an empty grammar will depend on the definition (of grammar) used. A grammar that has no productions is usually said to define the empty language, but any grammar whose set of possible terminal derivations is empty is also a candidate definition of the empty language.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what extended versions of BNF are completely standardized?

Comment: For instance, EBNF ("extended") and ABNF ("augmented").

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing logically wrong with allowing a grammar to have zero rules.  But such a grammar would be entirely useless, as it would not define any language (not even the empty-string by itself).

Comment: It defines the empty language, which is a language (and even a useful one).

Comment: "Useless" is an opinion, but it is incorrect to say that the empty grammar defines no language.